# Health effects of alcohol when out of date

Tags: alcohol

I know these days everything has to have an expiry date, but some things can be consumed for a long time after the date printed.

What, if any, would be the negative health effects of consuming out of date alcohol? In this instance; Archers. Still sealed, and kept at low temperature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can gather after reading through several different sites in a search, it will depend somewhat on the type of alcohol (I am assuming schnapps) and the method used to turn it into alcohol.

Archer appears to make liqueur type schnapps, which means that the fruit is steeped in the alcohol base, rather than distilled from the fruit itself. This means it will have a higher sugar content, and will go bad faster.

As near as I can tell, there isn't any adverse health effects reported from drinking out of date alcohol, but the taste can vary wildly, and be anything from a "flat" taste, to very harsh and bitter as the sugars continue to break down. This is moderated by temperature and how much air is in the bottle.

So there *shouldn't* be any health effects, other than possibly bad taste.

http://cocktails.about.com/od/stockyourbar/f/liquor_storage.htm

http://www.guntheranderson.com/liqueurs/storage.htm